# Kendo Datepicker setting value error

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-datepicker

Why this code does not set the value to input element?

```
<input id="datePicker" />
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
      value: new Date(),
      min: new Date()
    })
  });
</script>
<button>SetNewValue</button>
<script>
  $('button').on('click',function(){
    var dp = $("#datePicker").data('kendoDatePicker');
    dp.value(new Date(2016,1,1))
  })
</script>
```

If I change date to "new Date(2016, 4, 1)" value will be set correctly. 
The error appears in all browsers.

Link to JSbin example http://jsbin.com/catolumifa/edit?html,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to set past date "2016,1,1" because you have set minimum date as current date. so you cannot set older date than today.

so please remove below code lines from your code.

```
 min: new Date()
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for carelessness